# Opening a password protected pdf

Tags: pdf, passwords, password-recovery, password-protection

I received a pdf file few days back, the pdf file was password protected with a 5 digit number varying from 20000 to 25999. Unfortunately I forgot the password but still I remember that it falls within the mentioned set of numbers. Manually its really difficult for me to try each and every alternative one after another.

Kindly let me know if I want a brute force mechanism (or some other better option) then how to achieve this.

Comment: Don't know how to do it in java, but should be easy with [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/).

Comment: Okular with ignore author rights option?

Comment: Do you _really_ need a Java solution?

Comment: No need of java. Just need to recover it anyhow and thats it. I thought if nothing is available then will try in Java as the last option.

Comment: I bet a simple shell script would do the trick, just find a command line tool to open pwd-protected pdfs

Comment: @mwerschy Can you please explain how to achieve it easily in Autolt? I have never heard this name before and a wiki search tells its a freeware automation language for Microsoft Windows. Kindly explain

Comment: @7SLEVIN Presently I am running in a windows system...shall I need to install VMWare for converting the windows file system into UNIX file system virtually? Kindly explain

Comment: AutoIt will let you automate entering the password, so just have it loop from 20000 to 25999 and try them.

Comment: @mwerschy Any reference links for this? Since I don't have any idea of how to use it hence its really difficult to use :(

Comment: @yttrium Can you please explain further on your approach? I am looking for the easiest approach without any new learning (if feasible) :)

Comment: Just visit the link in my first comment and check the wiki? There's also a huge amount of examples provided with it. Open your file in a pdf viewer and automate entering the password...

Comment: Do you really need the number of do you just want to open the PDFs? Because IIRC Adobe reader was the only PDF reader which checked if a password was set, and all other readers just opened the PDF and ignored the 'a password is set' bit. After opening you can print it to a PDF writes, easily removing the password.

Comment: @Hennes: Which PDF apps are you talking about? It's been years since I've used Adobe's useless offering, and as far as I remember neither Foxit nor Sumatra nor the others ignored the user password. Older versions might have ignored the owner password (that restricts printing, copying etc.), but not the user password that prevented opening the file.

Comment: About xix years ago xpdf worked fine with a PDF from work. Only later I learned that I apparently needed a password to open it.

Comment: @Hennes: Hmm, I've no idea what the xpdf command-line utilities did *19* (!) years ago, but in my experience with them in the past mere half a decade or so they did not ignore the user password. Do you know of any programs that still do this that the OP can use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Linux/Unix/Cygwin you could automate the decryption by using qpdf and a loop that goes through all possible combinations:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Decrypting PDF file"

for i in $(eval echo "{20000..25999}"); do

echo "try nr. $i"
qpdf --password=$i --decrypt input.pdf output.pdf

RET=$?
if [[ $RET == 0 ]]; then
  echo "File succesfully decrypted."
  exit
fi

done
```

Others might be able to help you with getting this to work on Windows.